# How to Check If Two String Arrays are The Same

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve a problem on "practice it", and I'm not able to pass all the tests to it.

The problem is:

> Write a method called equals that takes in two string arrays and
>   returns true if they are equal; that is, if both arrays have the same
>   length and contain equivalent string values at each index.

I have tried the following code, but the test to the input 
`equals({"a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "d", "a", "e", "a"}, {"x", "b", "a", "c", "a", "d", "a", "e", "a"})` but it doesn't work.

```
public static boolean equals (String [] txt1, String [] txt2){
    boolean result=false;
    if(txt1.length==txt2.length){
        for(int i=0; i<txt1.length; i++){
            if(txt1[i].equals(txt2[i])){
                result = true;
            }
            else {
                result = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Expected return: `false`
My return: `true`

Comment: Replace `else result = false;` with `else return false;` - Your version essentially only checks if the last element of both arrays is equal

Comment: Can you try Arrays.equals(txt1, txt2)

Comment: @UnholySheep Can you make an Answer of that comment so this Question can be closed?

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank you!

Comment: I think the simplest way is to use diffutils library https://github.com/java-diff-utils/java-diff-utils/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<txt1.length; i++){
    if(txt1[i].equals(txt2[i])){
         result = true;
    }
    else {
         result = false;
    }
}
```

The `if` gets executed for every single element, so in essence your code only checks if the last element is the same for both arrays, as it overrides previous `result = false;` occurrences.

The correct solution is to immediately stop and return `false` once a single element is different:

```
for(int i=0; i<txt1.length; i++){
    if(txt1[i].equals(txt2[i])){
         result = true;
    }
    else {
         return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See explanation in comments:

```
public static boolean equals(String[] txt1, String[] txt2) {
    if (txt1.length == txt2.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < txt1.length; i++) {
            if (txt1[i].equals(txt2[i])) {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                // at this moment you know that arrays are different
                // so you can return false without checking the rest 
                // of the array
                return false;
            }
        }
        // here you checked all array, you know that each element is
        // same, because if it wouldn't, it would return false already
        // so you can return true now
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Some improvements can be made to your code, again read comments:

```
public static boolean equals(String[] txt1, String[] txt2) {
    if (txt1 == txt2) {
        // booth are null or booth are same instance
        return true;
    }
    if(txt1 == null || txt2 == null) {
        // one of the arrays is null so code bellow yould fail
        return false;
    }
    if (txt1.length == txt2.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < txt1.length; i++) {
            if (!txt1[i].equals(txt2[i])){
                // equal rewriten to not equal
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    // no need to write else since every branch in if will result in return
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the `for` loop you should check if the arrays aren't equal and if so return false. If the program doesn't return false, return true instead.

```
public static boolean equals(String[] txt1, String[] txt2) {
    if (txt1.length == txt2.length) {
        for(int i = 0; i < txt1.length; i++) {
            if(!txt1[i].equals(txt2[i])) {
               return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```